# Medicine before davening

Tags: medicine, shacharis-morning-prayer, eating

Suppose the doctor prescribes some medicine (consumed orally) that is supposed to be taken "first thing in the morning." It would still be effective if you waited until after davening to take it, but it's preferable to take it as soon as you wake up if possible (it's slightly more effective then, or you're less likely to forget about it).

Is there any reason that you should try to wait until after davening before taking the medicine the same way that you would wait before consuming food or can the medicine be taken before davening *l'chatchila*?

If it cannot be taken *l'chatchila*, are there any scenarios where it could be done? Some considerations that I can think of which might be relevant to the answer:

1. How severe the medical condition is which is being treated (or maybe it's not a medical condition at all like a dietary supplement to help build muscle).
2. What is the method of consuming the medication (e.g. taken as a pill, dissolved in something that is otherwise permissible to consume before davening [like water], dissolved in something that would not normally be consumed before davening, chewed and swallowed, etc.)
3. How much waiting affects the [efficacy or effectiveness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficacy) of the medicine.

Comment: I see you like my med questions :-) My understanding is that meds are not considered *achila* in general. I think the whole question is related specifically to eating before davening. If taking meds is not "eating" then, it seems that none of the items in your question would be of concern. Re water, IIRC SA states than one can drink water or coffee before davening.

Comment: @DanF what if it's chewable or drinkable medicine? What if it tastes bad so it must be dissolved in juice or something with a pleasant flavor? And what if it's a dietary supplement rather than really a medicine?

Answer (score 3):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in [סימן ח - דברים האסורים משהאיר היום עד לאחר שיתפלל](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0007_L2) where he discusses issues with eating and drinking before Shacharis.

He says that when in need, like an elderly person, it's preferable to daven at home first and then eat something and then go to shul.

> וְאִישׁ זָקֵן וְחָלוּשׁ שֶׁאֵינוֹ יָכוֹל לַעֲמֹד עַל נַפְשׁוֹ עַד עֵת יְצִיאַת הַצִּבּוּר מִבֵּית הַכְּנֶסֶת, בִּפְרָט בְּשַׁבָּתוֹת וְיָמִים טוֹבִים שֶׁמַּאֲרִיכִים הַרְבֵּה, יוֹתֵר טוֹב לְהַתִּיר לוֹ לְהִתְפַּלֵּל שַׁחֲרִית בְּבֵיתוֹ בְּנַחַת וִיקַדֵּשׁ וְיֹאכַל אֵיזֶה דָבָר, וְאַחַר כָּךְ יֵלֵךְ לְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת וִיכַוֵּן לִבּוֹ עִם הַצִבּוּר בִּתְפִלַּת שַׁחֲרִית וִיתְפַּלֵּל אַחַר כָּךְ עִמָּהֶם מוּסָף, וְלֹא שֶׁיִּשְׁתֶּה קַאפֶע עִם צוּקֶר (סֻכָּר) וְכַדּוֹמֶה בְּלֹא קַבָּלַת עֹל מַלְכוּת שָׁמַיִם תְּחִלָּה ‏

However, regarding medical needs, he permits (even) eating before davening, and doesn't require one to daven at home first.

> אַךְ לְצֹרֶךְ רְפוּאָה, מֻתָּר לֶאֱכֹל וְלִשְׁתּוֹת קֹדֶם הַתְּפִלָּה, שֶׁאֵין בָּזֶה מִשּׁוּם גֵּאוּת

Clearly taking medicine would also be allowed.

The Shulchan Aruch says the same in [סימן פט - הלכות תפלה וזמנה](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01975_part_6.html#HtmpReportNum0000_L2)

> **ג:** אָסוּר לוֹ לְהִתְעַסֵק בִּצְרָכָיו אוֹ לֵילֵךְ לַדֶּרֶךְ עַד שֶׁיִּתְפַּלֵּל תְּפִלַּת (י) י''ח <sub>וְיֵשׁ מְקִלִּין לְאַחַר שֶׁאָמְרוּ מִקְצָת בְּרָכוֹת קֹדֶם שֶׁאָמְרוּ בָּרוּךְ שֶׁאָמַר, וְטוֹב לְהַחְמִיר בָּזֶה (תְּרוּמַת הַדֶּשֶׁן סי' י''ח)</sub> וְלֹא לֶאֱכֹל וְלֹא לִשְׁתּוֹת, אֲבָל מַיִם (יא) מֻתָּר לִשְׁתּוֹת קֹדֶם תְּפִלָּה, בֵּין בְּחֹל וּבֵין (יב) בְּשַׁבָּת וְיוֹם טוֹב, וְכֵן אֳכָלִין וּמַשְׁקִין לִרְפוּאָה (יג) מֻתָּר.‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (**י**) י''ח. ואם אין השיירא ממתנת לו מותר לילך לדרך. מ''א ע''ש ועיין ט''ז: (**יא**) מותר. דלא שייך בהו גאוה. ועם צוק''ר אסור. ובמקום דצריך רפואה מותר לשתות מים וצוק''ר קודם שיתפלל הרדב''ז ח''ד סי' רל''ח ולאיש זקן וחלש שאינו יכול לעמוד על נפשו עד עת יציאת הציבור מבה''כ בפרט בשבתות וי''ט שלפעמים מתעכבין עד חצות יותר טוב להתיר לו להתפלל בביתו בנחת ויקדש ויאכל מידי בצפרא ואח''כ ילך לבה''כ ויכוין לבו עם הציבור בתפלת שחרית ויתפלל אחר כך עמהם מוספין של יום ולא שישתה הקא''וי או הגיקול''טי בלא קבלת עול מלכות שמים תחלה כי ודאי ע''ז נאמר ואותי השלכת אחר גויך. לקט הקמח. וכ''כ הפר''ח דקאו''י יכול לשתות ובפרט במצרים שאין הדעת מתיישב בלא קאו''י אבל קאו''י עם צו''קר או כל מיני תרגומא כדי שלא לשתות הקאו''י אליבא ריקנא אסור ע''ש ומהרח''ו ז''ל כתב דאפילו קם בחצות הלילה אסור למיטעם מידי עד אחר התפלה כמ''ש בזוהר. ושמעתי שאחד מן הגדולים התיר שתיית הקאו''י דדוקא מידי דמרבה דם אסור. יד אהרן: (**יב**) בשבת. ואחר תפלת מוסף אסור כיון שהגיע זמן קידוש. רש''ל: (**יג**) מותר. אפילו דבר דשייך בו גאוה כיון שאינו עושה משום גאוה אלא לרפואה אע''פ שאינו חולה שרי. מ''א: ‏

The Shulchan Aruch even includes hunger as an *illness* - allowing on to satiate one's hunger in order to daven properly.

> **ד:** הַצָּמֵא וְהָרָעֵב הֲרֵי הֵם בִּכְלַל הַחוֹלִים. אִם יֵשׁ בּוֹ יְכֹלֶת לְכַוֵּן דַּעְתּוֹ, יִתְפַּלֵּל. וְאִם לָאו, אִם רָצָה, אַל יִתְפַּלֵּל עַד שֶׁיֹּאכַל (יד) וְיִשְׁתֶּה.‏
>
> **באר היטב**  (**יד**) וישתה. הא דאמר אם רצה משמע שאינו מחויב. הטעם משום דעכשיו בזמן הזה בלא''ה אין מכוונים כ''כ ומ''מ אם רצה לאכול ולשתות קודם כדי שיכוין מותר עמ''א: ‏

Comment: What about things that aren't taken for _refuah_, but rather to improve overall health. Such as a dietary supplement to help build muscle?

Comment: @Daniel - how is that different from eating lunch?

Comment: Because A. The doctor recommended to take it ASAP in the morning and B. If it's a pill or a powder that is dissolved, it's not taken _derekh akhila_.

Comment: @Daniel - my apologies, I was thinking of another question when I wrote that. The key here is מִשּׁוּם גֵּאוּת - vanity - and I'm tempted to say that building muscles qualifies as a potential vanity issue. OTOH מִשּׁוּם גֵּאוּת may be referring to the method of eating or the food, and pills don't qualify as a "vanity" meal. (No vanity, no meal. Just "pure energy".)

Comment: What about a multivitamin? Muscle-building supplement wasn't meant to be davka. I'm just trying to push the boundaries of the ruling to find the edge-cases.

Comment: Also I'm just a little unsure of the scope of the _Kitzur SA_ that you mention since that siman seems to be about things that are prohibited before davening, but the example you brought mentions making kiddush, leaving me to wonder if he was writing specifically about Shabbat in that example.

Comment: @Daniel - same doubt: It's not a vanity-food, but borders on being vain as in "let's first take our multivitamin to keep healthy and then we'll also daven for health."